# Python: dictionary with keys having multiple values. How to print dictionary as set of dictionaries separating the list of values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary having keys with multiple values like this:

```
my_dict = {'key0': (0, 1), 'key1': (a, b), 'key2': (x, y)}
```

I would like print my dictionary like

```
my_dict = {'key0': 0, 'key1': a, 'key2': x}, {'key0': 1, 'key1': b, 'key2': y}
```

How can I achieve this? Please help...

Comment: Are all values size 2 tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all tuples are of the same length (i.e 2) you could use a list comprehension:

```
[{key: value[i] for key, value in my_dict} for i in range(2)]
```

Here is an example:

```
my_dict = {'key0': (0, 1), 'key1': (1, 2), 'key2': ('a', 'b')}
[{key: value[i] for key, value in my_dict.iteritems()} for i in range(2)]
```

Output:

```
[{'key0': 0, 'key1': 1, 'key2': 'a'}, {'key0': 1, 'key1': 2, 'key2': 'b'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no data structure like a = `{}, {}`. But, you can split the initial dict into 2 dicts:

```
my_dict = {'key0': (0, 1), 'key1': ('a', 'b'), 'key2': ('x', 'y')}
my_dict_1 = dict((key, value[0]) for key, value in my_dict.iteritems())
my_dict_2 = dict((key, value[1]) for key, value in my_dict.iteritems())
```

Results:

```
print my_dict_1
{'key0': 0, 'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'x'}
print my_dict_1
{'key0': 1, 'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'y'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your values are tuples/lists but could be of different sizes, you could do the following:

```
def expand_dict(input_dict):
    max_size = max(len(v) for v in input_dict.values())
    output_list = [dict() for _ in range(max_size)]
    for k, v in input_dict.items():
        for i, x in enumerate(v):
            output_list[i][k] = x
    return output_list

my_dict = {'key0': (0, 1), 'key1': ('a', 'b'), 'key2': ('x', 'y', 'z')}

print expand_dict(my_dict)
```

This prints:

```
[{'key2': 'x', 'key1': 'a', 'key0': 0}, {'key2': 'y', 'key1': 'b', 'key0': 1}, {'key2': 'z'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
>>> my_dict = {'key0': (0, 1), 'key1': (2, 3), 'key2': (4, 5)}
>>> dict_list = []
>>> for key in my_dict:
...    for index, item in enumerate(my_dict[key]):
...       if len(dict_list) >= index + 1:
...           dict_list[index][key] = item
...       else:
...           dict_list.append({key: item})
... 
>>> dict_list
[{'key2': 4, 'key1': 2, 'key0': 0}, {'key2': 5, 'key1': 3, 'key0': 1}]
```

This is quite efficient from the point of view of processing time and also covers all possible dict length cases (what if one of the tuples has 3 values not 2).

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution with complex example:

Used functions: `zip()` and `itertools.zip_longest()`

```
import itertools

my_dict = {'key0': (0, 1), 'key1': ('a', 'b'), 'key2': ('x', 'y'), 'key3': ('z', 'v')}
result = [dict(t) for t in itertools.zip_longest(*[list(zip([k,k],v)) for k,v in my_dict.items()])]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'key2': 'x', 'key0': 0, 'key1': 'a', 'key3': 'z'}, {'key2': 'y', 'key0': 1, 'key1': 'b', 'key3': 'v'}]
```